# Format a date from a timestamp without BST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, ecmascript-6

Consider the following timestamp I get back from the server:

```
2016-09-15T18:15:00.0000000
```

If I do the following:

```
function friendlyTime(timeslot) {
  const time = timeslot,
    timeDate = new Date(time),
    timeHours = `0${timeDate.getHours().toString()}`.slice(-2),
    timeMinutes = `0${timeDate.getMinutes().toString()}`.slice(-2);

  return `${timeHours}:${timeMinutes}`;
}

const slot = friendlyTime('2016-09-15T18:15:00.0000000');
```

I get back:

`19:15`, when what I really want is a reflection of the timestamp without **BST**, like `18:15`.

Is there an easy way to do this at all? My head explodes when it comes to dates and timezones in JavaScript.

It needs to look the same regardless of where anyone is in the world. It shouldn't be reflecting anyone's personal time settings.

Comment: The sting doesn't have an associated time zone so should be parsed as local and should represent 18:15 in every time zone (and will therefore represent a different time in each time zone with a different offset). By using UTC methods you getting the equivalent UTC time, which is also a different time in each time zone with a different offset. Just manipulate the string per Xotic750's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just manipulate the string, one possibility that would support [4 to 6 digit common spec years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (or more).

```js
function friendlyTime(timeslot) {
  return timeslot.split('T').pop().split(':', 2).join(':');
}
console.log(friendlyTime('2016-09-15T18:15:00.0000000'));
```

Another, if you only need to support 4 digit years. [(Javascript is spec'd for 4)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)

```js
function friendlyTime(timeslot) {
  return timeslot.slice(11, 16);
}
console.log(friendlyTime('2016-09-15T18:15:00.0000000'));
```

Comment: Yep, string manipulation is the go. Lots of ways to skin the cat, e.g. `('2016-09-15T18:15:00.0000000'.match(/\d\d:\d\d/) || [])[0]`. ;-)

Comment: This avoids any potential problems with timezones, so I accepted this answer, even though string manipulation 'feels' slightly weird with regard to extracting a time from a timestamp. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` use `getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()`. Also, as Mike McCaughan pointed out in comments, you have to add `Z` to the end of the string to make sure it will be parsed correctly in all browsers.

```js
function friendlyTime(timeslot) {
  const time = timeslot,
    timeDate = new Date(time),
    timeHours = `0${timeDate.getUTCHours().toString()}`.slice(-2),
    timeMinutes = `0${timeDate.getUTCMinutes().toString()}`.slice(-2);

  return `${timeHours}:${timeMinutes}`;
}

const slot = friendlyTime('2016-09-15T18:15:00.0000000Z');
console.log(slot);
```

Comment: I tried this before but it affected results if my timezone was Australia for example.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo It displays "18:15" no matter what your timezone is.

Comment: @Gothdo, isn't it browser-dependent without the "Z"?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You're right, it doesn't work correctly on Firefox.

Comment: I think to be as per spec, it would be `2016-09-15T18:15:00.000Z`, I will check.

Comment: Spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: Using a Date for this is not sensible. The OP string will be parsed using the host time zone offset, so will represent a different time in each time zone that it's displayed in.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I went with the other one simply because it was a lot clearer in its purpose and it removes any potential problems with timezones. I'm not sure what side effects manually adding the timezone to the end of the returned string would have. :)